# How to convert a tab-separated file into a comma-separated file?

Tags: csv, unix

I want to convert a tab-separated file into a CSV file. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 52):

The answer for OSX is different.

MacOS does not understand `\t` in the `sed` expression.

You have to insert the tab literal into the sed search pattern by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>tab</kbd> (see [How can I insert a tab character with sed on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398395/how-can-i-insert-a-tab-character-with-sed-on-os-x))

```
sed 's/ /,/g' input_file > output_file
```

Comment: On OSX you can use GNU sed that understands `\t`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x) is about how to install it.

Comment: What do you mean by "different"?  You haven't said what you're comparing with.

Answer (score 51):

You can use sed as:

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' input_file > output_file
```

This will keep the input file unchanged and will create a new file `output_file` with the changes.

If you want to change the input file itself without creating a new file you can use `-i` option to sed to do inplace changes:

```
sed -i 's/\t/,/g' input_file
```

Comment: This doesn't work in OS X, it seems to match the letter "t" and not a tab.

Comment: Instead of typing \t on OSX, press ctrl + v and then press tab

Comment: @codaddict, If I may ask, what is that `g` for in `'s/\t/,g'`?

Comment: @Les the `g` is to enable global substitution.... ref: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm "It is very important to note that sed substitutes only the first occurrence on a line. If the string root occurs more than once on a line only the first match will be replaced.

For the sed to perform a global substitution, add the letter g to the end of the command as follows"

Comment: OSX uses bsd style sed.  If you use a blank file extension mod it will work. `sed -i '' 's/foo/goo/g' somefile-name`  The blank is in single quotes after the -i.

Comment: How can we mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: @Ouss - we shouldn't, since it fails as soon as any value contains a comma or a (quoted) tab.

Comment: Aha… I sense an opportunity here

Comment: Now I see you provided the PERL solution. That's definitely the way to go. No need to reinvent the wheel. I would vouch for your answer. At the same time I believe that there is a place for the regex answer as well... Maybe you should edit your answer to include this "basic" solution for the case the `input_file` was "clean".

Answer (score 13):

Bear in mind that there are many flavours of comma-separated-value file.  Since you didn't specify one, I'll assume [RFC-4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) format, in UTF-8 encoding, and the TSV to be the same but using tabs instead of commas.

The naive approach would be to simply replace every tab with a comma:

```sh
tr '\t' ,
```

This falls down if any of the values already contain a comma, or if any contain a quoted tab.  You'll need to minimally parse the file, to maintain quoting.  Instead of hand-rolling such a parser, it's simpler, clearer and more flexible to use one already written, such as `Text::CSV` for Perl:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Text::CSV;

my $tsv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => "\t", auto_diag => 2 });
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();

while (my $row = $tsv->getline(*ARGV)) {
    $csv->print(STDOUT, $row) or die $csv->error_diag();
    print $/;
}
$csv->error_diag() unless $tsv->eof;
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also be achieved with Perl:

In order to pipe the results to a new output file you can use the following:
`perl -wnlp -e 's/\t/,/g;' input_file.txt > output_file.csv`

If you'd like to edit the file in place, you can invoke the -i option:
`perl -wnlpi -e 's/\t/,/g;' input_file.txt`

If by some chance you find that what you are dealing with is not actually tabs, but instead multiple spaces, you can use the following to replace each occurrence of two or more spaces with a comma:
`perl -wnlpi -e 's/\s+/,/g;' input_file`

Keep in mind that `\s` represents any whitespace character, including spaces, tabs or newlines and cannot be used in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

If the input_file did not contain commas nor quoted tabs, the easiest method is to use the sed command with a substitution regular expression that replaces tabs in the input_file with commas:

```
sed 's/\t/,/g' input_file > output_file
```

There is of course the case of input_files containing quoted tabs that will confuse the regex, also input_files that has values containing commas, these values should be quoted in output_files. Thee regex solution above would not be sufficient to address those cases.

One could think of several bash commands to "clean" the input file before processing it...

However, in the spirit of not reinventing the wheel. I would use a simple python3 script and store it in a file, let's call it: `tsv_to_csv_converter.py`:

```
import csv
import sys

tsv_file = sys.argv[1]
csv_file = sys.argv[2]

in_tsv = csv.reader(open(tsv_file, "r"), delimiter = '\t')
out_csv = csv.writer(open(csv_file, 'w'))

out_csv.writerows(in_tsv)
```

Of course, this code can be dramatically improved with exception catching, input value checks, a nice CLI interface, documentation.

The script can be used as follows:

```
python3 tsv_to_csv_converter.py input_file output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

After testing in MacOS, this is working for converting csv file to tsv file (suppose no tab or comma exists in the column values):

`cat file_input.tsv | tr '\t' ',' > file_output.csv`

I tried:

`sed 's/ /,/g' input_file > output_file`

and

`sed 's/\t/,/g' input_file > output_file`

However, neither of them worked.

Comment: Why the pointless `cat`?  Is there some reason you can't `tr <file_input.tsv`?  I don't see why you posted this, given that by your own admission it only works if there are no tabs or commas in the values, and there are plenty of similar answers with the same constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the usual easy-question-all-languages thing? Okay, here is my haskell solution:

```
main = interact (unlines . replTab . lines) where
  replTab l = l       >>= (\line ->
    "\"" ++ line "\"" >>= \char ->
    case char of
      '\t' -> "\",\""
      '"'  -> "\"\""
      _    -> [char]
    )
```

not tested, but should work.

PS: All the other solutions aren't aware of escaping commas.

Answer (score -1):

In UNIX replace all tabs with commas **in place**:

```
sed -i -e 's/\t/,/g' filename
```

Answer (score -1):

sed -e 's/TAB_CHAR/,/g' data.tsv > data.csv

The tricky part is how to enter the TAB character in command line, to do that:
Just hist "CTRL+V", then TAB

I frequently use this with mysql queries with -e parameter as described in this blog post http://blog.modsaid.com/2013/12/exporting-data-from-remote-mysql.html

Answer (score -2):

Try replacing all the tabs with commas.

Possibly with a regex like `s/\t/,/g`, if you don't have any quoted fields.

Or, you know, Excel could do that for ya.  Or R.  Or anything which can take in a TSV file.