# How can I insert a tab character with sed on OS X?

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have tried:

```
echo -e "egg\t  \t\t salad" | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\t/g'
```

Which results in:

```
eggtsalad
```

And...

```
echo -e "egg\t  \t\t salad" | sed -E 's/[[:blank:]]+/\\t/g'
```

Which results in:

```
egg\tsalad
```

What I would like:

```
egg salad
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Try: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Also, make sure you quote your sed expression if you include literal whitespace in it, otherwise the shell gets confused. This tripped me up at first.

Comment: This sucks when posting code in a forum or whatever, we can't post a literal TAB character.

Comment: @dongiulio According to the readline(3) manpage, "C-V" is by default a quoted-insert, which means that it will "Add the next character that you type to the line verbatim."

Comment: Why, Apple... WHY?!

Answer (score 46):

Use ANSI-C style quoting: `$'string'`

```
sed $'s/foo/\t/'
```

So in your example, simply add a `$`:

```
echo -e "egg\t  \t\t salad" | sed -E $'s/[[:blank:]]+/\t/g'
```

Comment: FWIW - if you add the $ using vim, in a 'sh' file with syntax on, will change the highlighting of the '\t' portion, so even vim knows the difference!

Comment: very useful, I agree this should be the answer but can someone explain why this magical $ works so fine?

Answer (score 26):

OSX's `sed` <s>only understands `\t` in the pattern, not in the replacement</s> doesn't understand `\t` at all, since it's essentially the ancient 4.2BSD `sed` left over from 1982 or thenabouts.  Use a literal tab (which in `bash` and `vim` is `Ctrl`+`V`, `Tab`), or install GNU `coreutils` to get a more reasonable `sed`.

Comment: Really? I couldn't get sed to understand \t in the pattern either. I used [[:blank:]] instead. Maybe I wasn't escaping it properly. -- Thanks.

Comment: Inside `"` quotes, the shell will have processed the backslash and `sed` won't see it.  With `sed`, and regexes in general, `'` quoting is strongly preferred.

Comment: Any chance of a code sample? It's not really important other than to satisfy my curiosity. echo -e "egg\tsalad" | sed -E 's/\t/_/' doesn't seem to work, neither does echo -e "egg\tsalad" | sed -E 's/\\t/_/'

Comment: ... *sigh* Lemme edit that out.  Just doublechecked; I thought FreeBSD/OSX had gotten a `sed` that was *slightly* smarter than the 4.2BSD one, but in fact the only character escape it supports is `\n`.

Comment: I have to admit, I get tripped by this kind of thing regularly because most of my experience is from the System III/V side of things and BSD is still somewhat foreign to me despite several years running FreeBSD and OS X.  (And most of my `sed` usage is in Linux.)

Comment: Oh well, it works for what I need it for, but it is annoying that OS X can't handle \t,\s, etc. - Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's obviously not the ancient `sed` from 1982, because then it wouldn't understand `[[:blank:]]`.  POSIX doesn't describe `\t` support in `sed`. Therefore, it would be nonconforming to support that. Converting `\t` to tab breaks shell scripts which rely on `sed` **not** to do that.

Answer (score 17):

Another option is to use `$(printf '\t')` to insert a tab, e.g.:

```
echo -e "egg\t  \t\t salad" | sed -E "s/[[:blank:]]+/$(printf '\t')/g"
```

Comment: This has the advantage of being more portable than `Ctrl+V Tab` since you can copy and paste the entire command and share it more easily without losing the control character.

Answer (score 1):

try awk

```
echo -e "egg\t  \t\t salad" | awk '{gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/,"\t");print}'
```

Answer (score -1):

A workaround for tab on osx is to use `"\    "`, an escape char followed by four spaces.

If you are trying to find the last instance of a pattern, say a `"    })};"` and insert a file on a newline after that pattern, your `sed` command on osx would look like this:

```
sed -i '' -e $'/^\    \})};.*$/ r fileWithTextIWantToInsert' FileIWantToChange
```

The markup makes it unclear: the escape char must be followed by four spaces in order for `sed` to register a tab character on osx.

The same trick works if the pattern you want to find is preceded by two spaces, and I imagine it will work for finding a pattern preceded by any number of spaces as well.