# linux command for introducing single space after each character in text file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a text file and I have to introduce single space after each character. The command that I am using is:

```
sed 's/./& /g' source.txt>output.txt
```

But I am not getting the output, output remains same as input.
Please help me regarding this. Is this command correct?

**external edit:** according to the comment below, the input text is: 'pustə́_pɾemí nù_kədé ví_kɪse_pyaːɾe mɪ'

and its corrsponding output is :   pustə́_pɾemí  nù_kədé  ví_kɪse_pyaːɾe  mɪ

Instead of introducing single space after each character it is replacing single space(which is already in input)with double space.

Comment: canna reproduce, works fine on linux

Comment: If you are using Mac OSX, the sed comes from BSD and not GNU. You can read about differences here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761361/sed-regex-problem-on-mac-works-fine-on-linux

Comment: no, I am not using Mac

Comment: input is:- pustə́_pɾemí nù_kədé ví_kɪse_pyaːɾe mɪ                   on executing sed command output is:-   pustə́_pɾemí  nù_kədé  ví_kɪse_pyaːɾe  mɪ                       .It is not introducing space after each character, but replacing single space (which is already in input) with double space.

Comment: it may be helpful to tell us that language that is

Answer (score 1):

Your sed command works for me, but the accents on the characters are moved from the character.

Here is a longer sed command that you can try, and it also works for me.

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

Comment: after executing sed 's/\(.\)/\1 /g' getting the same output as mentioned in question

Answer (score 0):

Here is an 'awk' option if 'sed' doesn't work

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {$i=$i " "}}1' source.txt > output.txt
```

[modified from here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/142815-insert-space-between-characters-using-sed.html)

edit: If you are using Mac OSX, 'sed' comes from BSD and not GNU. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524476/insert-space-after-period-using-sed) instructions how to add a single space and then modify to fit your needs.

Comment: It is showing the output but many of the garbage characters are also introduced

Comment: output is like this:-   p u s t É  Ì  _ p É Ÿ e m i Ì    n u Ì  _ k É  d e Ì    v i Ì  _ k É ª s e _ p y a Ë  É Ÿ e   m É ª  and its corresponding input is:-  pustə́_pɾemí nù_kədé ví_kɪse_pyaːɾe mɪ

Comment: -1 Can you explain why the sed solution doesn't work? This is a heck of a lot more complicated.

Comment: I am new to these commands. I don't know , I got somewhere this sed command that I am using.

Comment: The encoding may be due to your terminal. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820659/how-to-read-files-with-different-encodings-using-awk

Comment: @JohnKugelman this answer was added before it was known to be a locale issue. The sed command was working for everyone else, so the awk command was an attempt to not try to debug sed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sed` command is correct so it appears to me that you are running in to some locale issue.

On the prompt type the following and re-run your command:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```