# Replace all but first space with tabs

Tags: macos, bash, replace

I have a chain of piped bash commands

```
grep A01929 test_FTF89MNR.txt |
    grep status |
    tr "=" " " |
    tr "," " " |
    cut -d" " -f 1 -f 2 -f 11 -f 14 -f 17
```

which produces a whole bunch of output that looks like this

```
...    
2016-02-25 09:15:01.41 2742 1535 1796
...
```

To make import into Excel easy, I want to replace all of the white space between columns with TABS *except* the first one which separates the data and time. So the target output would be

```
...    
2016-02-25 09:15:01.41\t2742\t1535\t1796
...
```

Is there an easy command line fu that I can tack on to my chain of pipes to accomplish that? `tr` didn't seem to have something that allowed it to do ranges. I'm on OS X.

Comment: Showing input is always fine. Are we fine when tr replaces everything into tabs? And is A01929 always coming in ftont of status? Perhaps you can use something like `grep "A01929.*status" test_FTF89MNR.txt | tr "=," "\t" | cut -f1 -f2 -f11 -f14 -f17` (assuming only the date/time in the original file has a space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following trick with `sed`:  First replace all blanks with tabs, then replace exactly one.  Here's an example for illustration:

```
echo "a b c d" | sed 's/ /:/g;s/:/ /'
```

The first sed command `s/ /:/g` replaces globally (hence the g) all blanks with colons, and the second replaces the first colon with a blank.  This turns the string `a b c d` into `a b:c:d`.

Comment: If I use `\t`, it just puts in `t` characters. Bash won't let me actually enter a tab. :/

Comment: CTRL+V then TAB would insert a literal one in the command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398395/how-can-i-insert-a-tab-character-with-sed-on-os-x This may also help.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `awk` to specify the delimiters exactly.

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $5}' Input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting cute with sed could help you - replace them all then replace the first back, e.g.

`sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /1'`

e.g.

`$ echo "2016-02-25 09:15:01.41 2742 1535 1796" | sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /1'
2016-02-25 09:15:01.41  2742    1535    1796`

As pointed out in the comments, this is mac so that won't work. H[ere's a link to how to handle tabs on mac though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398395/how-can-i-insert-a-tab-character-with-sed-on-os-x)

Or, here's an all AWK version replacing all the pipes.

`awk '$0 ~ /A01929/ && $0~/status/ {gsub("=",""); gsub(",","");
     print $1 " " $2 "\t" $11 "\t" $14 "\t" $17}' test_FTF89MNR.txt`

Matches both the grepped values on a line, then substitues , and = for nothing, and then prints the desired delimiters.

Comment: In another comment trouble inputting literal tabs was reported since this is Mac - this would help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398395/how-can-i-insert-a-tab-character-with-sed-on-os-x

Comment: You should edit your answer to include this information, if you know that your current answer will not work.

Comment: `/A01929/ && /status/` is enough. Setting `-F'[=, ]` will eliminate gsubs, also if you set `OFS='\t'` will be cleaner for `print $1 " " $2, $11, $14, $17`

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer Merlin gave suggesting `awk`, you could replace your use of `cut` with `awk`, instead of doing additional post-processing. And you can replace your two calls to `tr` with one:

```
grep A01929 test_FTF89MNR.txt |
    grep status |
    tr "=," " " |
    awk '{print $1 " " $2 "\t" $11 "\t" $14 "\t" $17}'
```

With an excerpt from the original file, I'm sure someone could come up with an all-`awk` version.

Comment: Here's all awk:

`awk '$0 ~ /A01929/ && $0 ~ /status/ {gsub("=",""); gsub(",",""); print $1 " " $2 "\t" $11 "\t" $14 "\t" $17}' test_FTF89MNR.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed field data, you can use a `read` loop in Bash:

```
txt="2016-02-25 09:15:01.41 2742 1535 1796" 

while read -r da ti f1 f2 f3
do 
    printf "%s %s\t%s\t%s\t%s" $da $ti $f1 $f2 $f3
done <<< $txt
```